# How to decrease response time of a simple select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

`MarketPlane` table contains more than 60 million rows.

When I need the total number of plane from a particular date, I execute this query which takes more than 7 min. How can I reduce this time ?

```
SELECT COUNT(primaryKeyColumn) 
FROM   MarketPlan 
WHERE  LaunchDate > @date
```

I have implemented all things mentioned in your links even now I have implemented `With(nolock)` which reduce response time is to 5 min.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 and cluster index on LaunchDate

Comment: If you already have a clustered index on LaunchDate, you shouldn't be seeing 7min plus query times? How many records are you retrieving at a time?

Comment: @OMG - Why wouldn't a Clustered Index on a DateTime column improve performance? The query is a range scan which would allow for a fast range index lookup as all data would be in sequential blocks? Semi-related... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177416.aspx

Comment: 60 million records is also into the point where the setup of the disks that the data is on can make a considerable difference.  Optimization of a database gets a lot more involved as it grows.

Comment: launchDate's data type is Date in Sql Server 2008.

Comment: @Jeevan - Do you have the Execution Plan for the current query?

Comment: @Jeevan - Might suggest you start there and see what is actually happening when you run the query above. Once you see how the current query is being executed it will be easier to identify the bottleneck and what can be done to address it.

Comment: @Calgary Coder- thanks, How to get execution plan ?

Comment: @Jeevan - In SQL Management Studio, pressing <CTRL+M> toggles the "Show Execution Plan". Press <CTRL+M> before executing the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to [create an index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on the table, or maybe [partition the table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/) by date.

You might also want to have a look at

[SQL Server 2000/2005 Indexed View Performance Tuning and Optimization Tips](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/indexed_views_p1.aspx)

[SQL Server Indexed Views](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3867651/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views.htm)

Comment: it is quite informative but does not work in my scenario because i have implemented all thing mention in link.

Answer (score 0):

Does the table in question have an index on the `LaunchDate` column? Also, did you really mean to post `LaunchDate>@date`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL-Server based on @date, although the same can be applied to most databases.

If your primary query is to select out a range of data (based on sample), adding, or altering the CLUSTERED INEDX will go a long way to improving query times.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx

By default, SQL-Server creates the Primary Key as the Clustered Index which is great from a transactional point of view, but if your focus is to retrieve the data, then altering that default makes a huge difference.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX name ON MarketPlan (LaunchDate DESC)
```

Note: Assuming LaunchDate is a static date value and is primarily inserted in increasing/sequential order to minimize index fragmentation.

Comment: Topic starter wrote in his first comment to main post that he has  clustered index on LaunchDate column

Comment: @vgv8 - Yes, that detail was added after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fine suggestions here, if all else fails, consider a little denormalization, create another table with the cumulative counts and update it with a trigger. If you have more queries of this nature think about OLAP

Comment: I don't want to use OLAP because on it I have to write MDX query for geting data and every time when new record inserted then i will have to process cube.which i don't want.

Comment: @Jeevan Bhatt, Both of your statments are wrong. SQL and real-time (it is  ROLAP mode, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950948/microsoft-sql-server-analysis-services-olap-cube/3953196#3953196 ) processing are possible in cube

Comment: @vg8- yes, real time processing is there in ROLAP but did't u think due to this it i will have to use MDX?

Comment: @Jeevan Bhatt, MDX in cubes is just a convenience. You can use SQL there

Comment: SQL can be used in ROLAP since all the data and metadata are stored in relational source database. SSAS is used only for processing without deployment. Default MOLAP can use only MDX

Answer (score 0):

Your particular query does not require clustered key on the date column. It would actually run better with nonclustered index with the leading date column because you don't need to do key lookup in this query, so the nonclustered index would be covering and more compact than clustered (it implicitly includes clustered key columns).
If you have it indexed properly and it still does not perform it is most likely fragmentation. In this case defragment the index and try again.

Comment: Vaso is correct.  The total IO for reading a non-clustered index is less than reading the clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new index like this:

CREATE INDEX xLaunchDate on MarketPlan (LaunchDate, primaryKeyColumn)

Check this nice article about how an index can improve the performance.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/08/sql-server-query-optimization-remove-bookmark-lookup-remove-rid-lookup-remove-key-lookup-part-2/

Comment: This does not make when cluster index is on LaunchDate, as topic starter wrote in his first comment.

Answer (score 0):

> "WHERE  LaunchDate > @date"

Is the value of parameter @date defined in the same batch (or transaction or context)?
If not, then this would lead to Clustered Index Scan (of all rows) instead of Clustered Index Seek (of just rows satisfying WHERE condition) if its value is coming from outside of current batch (as, for example, input parameter of stored procedure or udf function).
The query cannot be fully optimized by SQL Server optimizer (at compile time) leading to full table scan since the value of parameter is known only at run-time

Update:  Comment to answers proposing OLAP.
OLAP is just concept, SSAS cubes is just one of the possible ways of OLAP implementation.
It is convenience, not obligation in getting/using OLAP concept.
You have not use SSAS to use OLAP concept.
See, for ex., [Simulated OLAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483/simulated-olap/42504#42504)

Update2: Comment to question in comments [to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222095/how-to-decrease-response-time-of-a-simple-select-querry/4222371#4222371):

- [MDX performance vs. T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672754/mdx-performance-vs-t-sql)

MDX is an option/convenience/feature/functionality provided by SSAS (cubes/OLAP) not obligation

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is:

```
SELECT COUNT(LaunchDate) 
FROM   MarketPlan 
WHERE  LaunchDate > @date
```

This will guarantee you index-only retrieval for any LaunchDate index.

Also (this depends on your execution plan), I have seen instances (but not specific to SQL Server) in which > did a table scan and BETWEEN used an index.  If you know the top date you might try `WHERE LaunchDate BETWEEN @date AND <<Literal Date>>`.

Comment: If the only index is clustered one on LaunchDate column, then there is no difference between "SELECT COUNT(LaunchDate)", "SELECT COUNT(primaryKeyColumn)" or "SELECT COUNT(*)" since this clause (counting) is applied already after extraction according to "WHERE" condition. I.e. "WHERE LaunchDate > @date" cannot select rows with NULL LaunchDate and primaryKeyColumn cannot contain NULL

Answer (score 0):

How wide is the table?  If the table is wide (ie: many columns of (n)char, (n)varchar  or xml) there might be a significant amount of IO causing the query to run slowly as a result of using the clustered index.

To determine if IO is causing the long query time perform the following:

1. Create a non-clustered index only on the LaunchDate column.
2. Run the query below which counts LaunchDate and forces the use of the new index.

   SELECT COUNT(LaunchDate)

   FROM   MarketPlan WITH (INDEX = TheNewIndexName)

   WHERE  LaunchDate > @date

I do not like to use index hints and I only suggest this hint only to prove if the IO is causing long query times.

Comment: What can else, except IO, be causing a long query time on 70-million rows table?

Comment: vgv8 - the question was marked as answered when my post was made.  My entry was to add another point which I did not feel was included in the othere posts clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1. First create a clustered index on the date column, since query is date range specific, all the data will be in the actual order and this will avoid having to scan through all records in the table
2. You can try using Horizontal partioning, this will affect your existing table design but this is the most optimal way to do so, see this
   http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/