# Why isn't index likely to do much if it's DATETIME or DATETIME2 because they include the time portion?

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, indexing, clustered-index

Comments to [question "How to decrease response time of a simple select query?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222095/how-to-decrease-response-time-of-a-simple-select-querry) tell:

- "What is the data type on LaunchDate? An index isn't likely to do much if it's DATETIME or DATETIME2 because they include the time portion – OMG Ponies"
- "@OMG - Why wouldn't a Clustered Index on a DateTime column improve performance? The query is a range scan which would allow for a fast range index lookup as all data would be in sequential blocks? Semi-related...msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177416.aspx – Calgary Coder"
- "Calgary Coder: **DATETIME/2 includes time -- an index, clustered or non-clustered, would be good for dates with duplicate times but not ranges**. – OMG Ponies"

I created a test table with clustered index on `DATETIME` type column `LaunchDate` and observe index seeks for queries similar to cited in above question:

```
SELECT COUNT(primaryKeyColumn) 
FROM   MarketPlan 
WHERE  LaunchDate > @date
```

instead  of table or index scans.

Why wouldn't a clustered index on a `DateTime` column improve performance?
Why isn't index likely to do much if it's `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` because they include the time portion?

I'd appreciate a script illustrating that indexing of `DATETIME` column does not improve performance.

Update: Also, Did OMG imply that index on `DATE` type column would be helpful but not `DATETIME` and `DATETIME2`?

Comment: I think OMG was wrong in this case. **The indexing should be helpfull**.

Comment: A range of *times alone* (e.g., 8:00–10:00) will not be improved by an index when there are multiple dates in the column. But that doesn't really seem to be what he's talking about. I have no idea.

Comment: That's what I get for not locking my workstation :/

Comment: I could not understand what was someone getting while not locking workstation and what was the range of times ((e.g., 8:00–10:00) for date values in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've read the other question, no idea what OMG ponies means

**3 points**:

- It shouldn't matter if an index is clustered or non-clustered:
- It doesn't matter  whether time is included too
- It just has to be useful

**Seek or scan**:

Based on statistics, if `LaunchDate > @date` means, say, 90% of the rows, then most likely a scan will happen. If it is quite selective, then a seek is more likely.

Regardless of clustered or non-clustered!

**What index?**

A query like this would require an index on LaunchDate and primaryKeyColumn

```
SELECT COUNT(primaryKeyColumn) 
FROM   MarketPlan 
WHERE  LaunchDate > @date
```

Now, any non-clustered index refers to the clustered index which is assumed to the PK by default. So primaryKeyColumn is implicitly included already.

**Superstition**

However, `COUNT(primaryKeyColumn)` [is a superstition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649). Because PKs do not allow NULL, it is equivalent to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   MarketPlan 
WHERE  LaunchDate > @date

SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM   MarketPlan 
WHERE  LaunchDate > @date
```

So you only need an index on LaunchDate, whether clustered or non-clustered

Comment: The comment to question told about having clustered index on  LaunchDate but not primaryKeyColumn. In such a table with 10 rows of data (and 5 columns) I observe Clustered Index Seek if LaunchDate > @date means, say, any number of rows 0%, 10%, 20%, 30%, 90%, 100%

Comment: @vgv8: 10 rows is peanuts. You'd need 10k rows. As I said, it's how useful an index would be, not C or NC. There is no need to use primaryKeyColumn which simplifies the index

Comment: Why/how does primaryKeyColumn simplify the index?

Comment: @vgv8: sorry, *not* using it in the index: see my COUNT(*) vs COUNT(1) stuff

Answer (score 0):

Index on a date column will not be use  if your application use datetime which cause implicit data type conversion . If you look on the execution plan you can see that there is an internal function applied to a column. Solution is change the date column to timestamp(4) or adjust client application to use date instead of datetime.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about here, but the only `timestamp` data type defined for SQL Server (for which this question is tagged) has nothing whatsoever to do with dates and times.